# Microsoft Translator API Java IncludeMultipleMTAlternatives

Tags: java, azure, translate

I need help to set the IncludeMultipleMTAlternatives in my request. I don't know how to enable it.

I get only one result back. Can anybody help please? Thank you.

My code:

```js
            // Get the access token
            String key = "*********************************";
            String authenticationUrl = "https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/sts/v1.0/issueToken";
            HttpsURLConnection authConn = (HttpsURLConnection) new URL(authenticationUrl).openConnection();
            authConn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            authConn.setDoOutput(true);
            authConn.setRequestProperty("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", key);
            IOUtils.write("", authConn.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8");
            String token = IOUtils.toString(authConn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8");
            System.out.println(token);
            
            // Using the access token to build the appid for the request url
            String appId = URLEncoder.encode("Bearer " + token, "UTF-8");
            String text = URLEncoder.encode("house", "UTF-8");
            String from = "en";
            String to = "de";
            String translatorTextApiUrl = String.format("https://api.microsofttranslator.com/v2/http.svc/Translate?appid=%s&text=%s&from=%s&to=%s", appId, text, from, to + "&maxTranslations=5&IncludeMultipleMTAlternatives=true");
            HttpsURLConnection translateConn = (HttpsURLConnection) new URL(translatorTextApiUrl).openConnection();
            translateConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            translateConn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/xml");
            String resp = IOUtils.toString(translateConn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8");
            System.out.println(resp);
```

I want to get this result.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDBxD.jpg)

Comment: Hi, does my code works for you ?

Comment: Thank you Jay, I can only test him tomorrow. After the test I will answer directly

Comment: Sure, waiting for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

According to your needs,it seems that you called the incorrect `REST API` in your java code.

You should use 
`https://api.microsofttranslator.com/v2/http.svc/GetTranslations` if you want set `IncludeMultipleMTAlternatives` property and get more than one alternatives from `MT engine`,not `https://api.microsofttranslator.com/V2/Http.svc/Translate`.

Please refer to the complete description from [official tutorial](http://docs.microsofttranslator.com/text-translate.html#!/default/post_GetTranslationsArray).

Here is my sample code for your reference.

```
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;

import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

public class Test1 {
    private static String key = "<your translator account key>";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            // Get the access token
            // The key got from Azure portal, please see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/cognitive-services-apis-create-account
            String authenticationUrl = "https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/sts/v1.0/issueToken";
            HttpsURLConnection authConn = (HttpsURLConnection) new URL(authenticationUrl).openConnection();
            authConn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            authConn.setDoOutput(true);
            authConn.setRequestProperty("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", key);
            IOUtils.write("", authConn.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8");
            String token = IOUtils.toString(authConn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8");
            System.out.println(token);

//          Using the access token to build the appid for the request url
            String appId = URLEncoder.encode("Bearer " + token, "UTF-8");
            String text = URLEncoder.encode("Hello", "UTF-8");
            String from = "en";
            String to = "fr";
            String translatorTextApiUrl = String.format("https://api.microsofttranslator.com/v2/http.svc/GetTranslations?appid=%s&text=%s&from=%s&to=%s&maxTranslations=5", appId, text, from, to);
            HttpsURLConnection translateConn = (HttpsURLConnection) new URL(translatorTextApiUrl).openConnection();
            translateConn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            translateConn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/xml");
            translateConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml");
            translateConn.setDoOutput(true);
            String TranslationOptions = "<TranslateOptions xmlns=\"http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Microsoft.MT.Web.Service.V2\">" +
                    "<Category>general</Category>" +
                    "<ContentType>text/plain</ContentType>" +
                    "<IncludeMultipleMTAlternatives>True</IncludeMultipleMTAlternatives>" +
                    "<ReservedFlags></ReservedFlags>" +
                    "<State>contact with each other</State>" +
                    "</TranslateOptions>";
            translateConn.setRequestProperty("TranslationOptions", TranslationOptions);
            IOUtils.write("", translateConn.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8");
            String resp = IOUtils.toString(translateConn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8");
            System.out.println(resp);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
}
```

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, it's not possible.

I want to translate picture from en to de.

The result at bing is:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJJB0.png)

And the result in my code is:

```html
<GetTranslationsResponse xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Microsoft.MT.Web.Service.V2" 
xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><From>en</From><Translations><TranslationMatch>
<Count>0</Count><MatchDegree>100</MatchDegree><MatchedOriginalText/><Rating>5</Rating>
<TranslatedText>Bild</TranslatedText></TranslationMatch></Translations></GetTranslationsResponse>
```

I've try to change https://api.microsofttranslator.com/v2/http.svc/GetTranslations
to 
https://api.microsofttranslator.com/V2/Http.svc/GetTranslationsArray

but there ist an error

```html
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
 at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210)
 at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
 at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465)
 at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:503)
 at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:983)
 at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:940)
 at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:105)
 at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
 at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:286)
 at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
 at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:735)
 at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:678)
 at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:706)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1587)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1492)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:263)
 at microsoft.translator.Translator.translate(Translator.java:48)
 at microsoft.translator.MicrosoftTranslatorMain.main(MicrosoftTranslatorMain.java:10)
```